# How to disable touch screen right click in Wayfire/Wayland?

Tags: raspberry-pi, wayland, touch-screen, libinput, kiosk

I've created a touch screen kiosk using a RPi 5 running the latest OS (eg. Bookworm + Wayfire). I'm trying to disable right-click events as they are super annoying for my use-case.

A right click action is generated if I touch > drag > hold > release the touch screen - these often get triggered accidently.

If I look at the raw touchscreen events using `libinput` or `evtest` there are no discrete `BTN_RIGHT` events only `BTN_TOUCH`. However, if I attach a regular mouse I can see `BTN_RIGHT` events. Adding the following file to `/etc/libinput/local-overrides.quirks` disables the right clicks for the mouse.

```
[Disable right mouse button on system]
MatchUdevType=mouse
AttrEventCodeDisable=BTN_RIGHT
```

Question is, how can I achieve the same result for the touch screen when there is no discrete `BTN_RIGHT` event. Presumably this is being generated (synthesised) somehere?

There doesn't appear to be an option I've found in the `~/.config/wayfire.ini`, but of course I'm open to any options (except installing X Windows!).

**Raw touch screen events:**

```
 $ libinput debug-events /dev/input/event3
 ...
 event3   TOUCH_MOTION            +0.804s   0 (0) 22.50/68.88 (108.00/551.00mm)
 event3   TOUCH_FRAME             +0.804s   
 event3   TOUCH_MOTION            +0.815s   0 (0) 22.08/68.88 (106.00/551.00mm)
 event3   TOUCH_FRAME             +0.815s   
 event3   TOUCH_MOTION            +0.826s   0 (0) 21.88/68.88 (105.00/551.00mm)
 event3   TOUCH_FRAME             +0.826s   
 event3   TOUCH_MOTION            +0.847s   0 (0) 21.67/68.88 (104.00/551.00mm)
 event3   TOUCH_FRAME             +0.847s   
 event3   TOUCH_UP                +0.868s   0 (0)
 event3   TOUCH_FRAME             +0.868s


$ evtest /dev/input/event3
...
Event: time 1705232617.339595, type 3 (EV_ABS), code 53 (ABS_MT_POSITION_X), value 108
Event: time 1705232617.339595, type 3 (EV_ABS), code 0 (ABS_X), value 108
Event: time 1705232617.339595, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
Event: time 1705232617.350325, type 3 (EV_ABS), code 53 (ABS_MT_POSITION_X), value 106
Event: time 1705232617.350325, type 3 (EV_ABS), code 0 (ABS_X), value 106
Event: time 1705232617.350325, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
Event: time 1705232617.361048, type 3 (EV_ABS), code 53 (ABS_MT_POSITION_X), value 105
Event: time 1705232617.361048, type 3 (EV_ABS), code 0 (ABS_X), value 105
Event: time 1705232617.361048, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
Event: time 1705232617.382822, type 3 (EV_ABS), code 53 (ABS_MT_POSITION_X), value 104
Event: time 1705232617.382822, type 3 (EV_ABS), code 0 (ABS_X), value 104
Event: time 1705232617.382822, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
Event: time 1705232617.403488, type 3 (EV_ABS), code 57 (ABS_MT_TRACKING_ID), value -1
Event: time 1705232617.403488, type 1 (EV_KEY), code 330 (BTN_TOUCH), value 0
Event: time 1705232617.403488, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
```